# Microsoft graph - sharepoint - Limit permissions to only one folder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

is posible set limit permissions `Files.ReadWrite.All`, `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `Sites.ReadWrite.All` for specific application only for one folder ?

It is used application permission without user token.